# Is there a standard terminology for a class that actually does all the heavy work to create a dumb (immutable) related class?

Tags: terminology

Say that creating/calculating all the properties of fruit needs a lot of logic, and you just want to have a very simple immutable POCO object in the end.

So i.e. it doesn't have any methods, making it really easy to reason about, and also easily and clearly serializable.

Right now I have something names like this:

```
class BananaCalulator { public Banana Calculate() }
class Banana {}
class AppleCalulator { public Apple Calculate() }
class Apple {}
```

Is this a common pattern? Is there a more common terminology instead of Calculator?

Comment: I'd say Factory ...

Comment: I think we'd need to know a bit more about what these two classes do in order to answer this. For instance, is Apple an interface that AppleCalculator implements? Then it's factory as @SilviuBurcea said. Is AppleCalculator an old/bad API that you're trying to wrap in something more sensible? Then it's probably wrapper or adapter.

Comment: `BananaCalculator` has a lot of logic that I don't want to have in the `Banana` result, because after it has been calculated all this code (and extra methods) makes it harder to reason about - they will be an unnecessary distraction.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea, thanks for your answer. Wiki says though: "In class-based programming, the factory method pattern is a creational pattern which uses factory methods to **deal with the problem of creating objects without specifying the exact class of object that will be created.**" That's not applicable in this case. I do exactly know what class to create.

Comment: As Silviu points out, this is generally known as some kind of factory. In particular, those `Calculate()` methods are factory methods (which are [related to, but distinct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern#Definition) from the Factory Method *Pattern*). However, a class whose sole responsibility is acting as a constructor for another class might be an instance of the [Builder Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern). Builders tend to have fluent interfaces such as `var banana = Banana.Builder().Weight(130g).Length(21cm).Build()`.

Comment: @DirkBoer Are you trying to say that BananaCalculator has some methods that return a Banana? And there is no inheritance or polymorphism going on with either class? If so then I'd agree with amon that Builder is much closer than Factory.

Comment: @Ixrec, that's right. Sorry if I was unclear. I think amon is right. If he makes it an answer I'll accept!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Gang of Four](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) knows two patterns which describe objects which do nothing but create other objects.

One is the Factory.

The other is the Builder.

The difference between the two is that a Factory receives all arguments with a single method-call and usually can be reused to create more objects of the same type, a Builder has a number of methods which define the properties of the created object until a build-method is called. The Builder is often (but not necessarily) not reusable afterwards.

```
BananaFactory factory = new BananaFactory();
Banana b1 = factory.createBanana(100, 200);
Banana b2 = factory.createBanana(110, 210);

BananaBuilder builder = new BananaBuilder();
builder.setLength(100);
builder.setWeight(200),
Banana b3 = builder.build();
```

Comment: For the factory, it's often actually a (static) `getBananaFactory()`. Or in languages supporting free functions, a free function to get the factory object or even a free function *being* the factory.